# JQuery selector not working in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a viewA and corresponding ControllerA but on click of an image on viewA i have to navigate to another ViewB and corresponding ControllerB, in ViewB have some check boxes then have a button on viewB that takes us to ViewA, then again i want to click the image on ViewA and Navigate to ViewB and restore the checkBox values (Checked, Unchecked). I have stored the values of checkboxes to service variable.

Comment: soo the question is???

Comment: not able to select the checkBoxes using jquery selector $ ("#checkBoxId").prop('checked', serviceVariableValue);

Comment: post your code or what you have tried.

Comment: if (EatService.goingToFilter == true)
 {
if ($scope.providerName == 'zomato')
{
  $('#rated').prop("checked", EatService.Rated);
  

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app='demo'>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <h1> viewA </h1>
    <a href="#/about"><img src="src" /></a>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
    <h1> viewB </h1>
    <h4>Click me to see ViewA: <input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change='checkView()'></h4>
</script>

<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

script:

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

demo.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {});

demo.controller('AboutController', function ($scope,$location) {
    $scope.checkView=function(){
    //if($scope.checked)
    if($('#myCheckBox').prop('checked') == true)
        $location.url('/home');
  }
});

demo.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

[**TRY THIS CODE**](https://jsfiddle.net/qe41Lvwc/):